# Conditional proposition

Tags: logic

I was looking for proof of conditional proposition, trying to understand why it is always true when it's hypothesis is false. While I was researching I found theories like material implication and objections of it's paradoxes and so on. And it was enough to convince myself. But the thing is that these arguments are all end up with it's counterargument. My question is: have the material implication arguments been proved?
If so, where can I find this proof in a mathematical, not philosophical way? 
If it just remains in not being proved, then how we can use the conditional operator in a mathematical proof?

Comment: It is a definition (or convention): the *conditional* (or *material implication*) used in "standard" mathematical discourse is modelled with the well-known truth table.

Comment: The key-feature of the *conditional* in mathematics is its use in *modus ponens*: when $P$ is *true* and $P \to Q$ is *true* we want to be licensed to infer $Q$, i.e. we want that $Q$ is *true* also.

Comment: When $P$ is *false*... well, we are not interested into what we can infer from *false* premises.

Comment: You can find many related posts on this site, searching for *conditional* or *material implication*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, one more thing, is the argument: P→Q is equivalent with ~p or q just argument or mathmatical law?

Comment: With the truth-functional definition of $P \to Q$, i.e. $P \to Q$ is *false* only in case that $P$ is *true* and $Q$ is *false* (see truth table) it is straightforward to check that it is equivalent to $\lnot P \lor Q$.

Comment: You can see David Sanford, [If P Then Q: Conditionals and the Foundations of Reasoning](https://books.google.it/books?id=PcWLAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Routledge (1989).

Comment: @Jin Not everything in mathematics is proved. Some things one needs to assume to be true so one has a springboard from where to jump from. These things are called axioms and inference rules. Choosing what axioms and rules to choose as starting point is a partly philosophical endeavor, that's necessary.

Comment: As well as : Jonathan Bennett, [A Philosophical Guide to Conditionals](https://books.google.it/books?id=ReYTDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Oxford UP (2003).

Comment: The *conditional* is a [connective](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/connectives-logic/index.html): it does not need "a proof": it is part of the symbolic language. [Modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) is based on it: it is a *rule of inference*: one of the "basic" ones.

Comment: You can see: Ethan Bloch, [Proofs and Fundamentals: A First Course in Abstract Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=QJ_537n8zKYC&pg=PA53), Springer (2nd ed., 2011) **Ch2.2 Direct Proofs**, for a discussion regarding the fact that "the statement of virtually every theorem, when viewed appropriately, is of the form $P \to Q$, or some combination of such statements."

Comment: Thank you for your all reply with the helpful books :) This will get me into more deeper math. Have a good day!